# find data type of the output column

Tags: sql, teradata

An Example:

```
sel  date '2008-03-07'- date '2009-04-10' 

    (2008-03-07-2009-04-10)
1   -399
```

What would be the data type of the result here?

It's INTERVAL DAY (please correct if this is wrong) here in this case I know but, is there a function available to return the data type characteristics of the resultant column?

Comment: ... What exactly are you expecting this mystery function to return?  A text string of the type name? The integer value?  What are you planning on doing with this information/why do you think you need it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistery function is called TYPE :-)

```
select  type(date '2008-03-07'- date '2009-04-10')
```

It's not INTERVAL DAY, it's an INTEGER. 
You only get INTERVALS when you request them explicitly, but they're hardly used as the maximum number of digits is only 4:

```
select  date '2008-03-07'- date '2009-04-10' MONTH(4)
```